# Python selenium script stops working after a few hours

Tags: python, linux, selenium, background-process

I am running a python script on a linux server 4.9 kernel. This script uses selenium to open a firefox instance and load some website. The script is supposed to be running for days. Since I am running the process over ssh, I have tried both screen and nohup, but the process just stops after a few hours.

I can see the python process using top but its terminal output is just paused. I am unable to understand why is this happening.

Answer (score 0):

I met the similar situation recently. It looks like that the antivirus software on my laptop interrupted the geckodriver in the middle. I turn off that software and now it keep running.